# Запуск программы на другом пользователе с правами администратора

Tags: c#, windows

Суть заключается в том, что у меня есть служба, которая запускается от `LOCAL_SYSTEM`, то есть с правами администратора. Мне нужно чтобы она запускала программу на другом пользователе с правами администратора.

Например служба будет запускать `regedit.exe`, на пользователе `exampleuser`(для примера). То есть вроде бы служба находиться в `LOCAL_SYSTEM`, но при этом окно реестра запустилось на `exampleuser`.

Comment: `runas` https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2018/01/15/runas-sposoby-zapustit-programmu-ot-imeni-drugogo-polzovatelya/

Comment: @aepot runas ведь запускает программу на текущем юзере от имени другого, а мне нужно чтобы программа запускалась на другом пользователе.

Comment: А вы попробовали? _на текущем юзере от имени другого_ - это как?